# Unity Multiplayer client does not properly set a parent for spawned object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

So I spawn players and than guns that they have, on a host it works perfectly but on a client guns do not become instance of an object. Here's the code

```
 [Command]
 void CmdSpawn() {
     gun = (GameObject)Instantiate(gunToEquip, weaponPosition.position, weaponPosition.rotation);

     NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(gun, connectionToClient);
     gun.transform.parent = weaponPosition;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you aren't setting the parent on client. Only on the server. The host is server and client at the same time so it works. Second - have you dragged a gun prefab into network manager's spawnable prefabs slot?

Also, I believe you shouldn't be doing it like so:

```
gun.transform.parent = weaponPosition;
```

Use that instead:

```
gun.transform.SetParent(weaponPosition);
```

Try that:

```
[Command]
void CmdSpawn() 
{
    gun=(GameObject)Instantiate(gunToEquip,weaponPosition.position,weaponPosition.rotation);
    gun.transform.SetParent(weaponPosition);
    RpcSpawn();
}

[ClientRpc]
void RpcSpawn()
{
    if(NetworkServer.active) return;
    gun = (GameObject)Instantiate(gunToEquip, weaponPosition.position, weaponPosition.rotation);
    gun.transform.SetParent(weaponPosition);
}
```

Comment: Yes I dragged a gun prefab into network manager's spawnable prefabs, so how to make it spawn on a client too?

Comment: Oh, it isn't spawning at all? Try NetworkServer.Spawn(gun);

Comment: I'm sorry, that was stupid, how to make it spawn on a client as a child of weaponPosition, because it spawns, but just stays in the middle of the map for both player on a client, meanwhile host does this properly

Comment: I actually send an rpc to spawn an object, which needs to be parented to something else(and don't use NetworkServer.Spawn then). But be careful, make sure not to spawn the object twice(because host is 2 in 1 - client and server) You can check NetworkServer.active inside and rpc - if it is true - abort

Comment: Sooo, how to spawn it so it becomes a child of WeaponPosition?

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Ok so it works, partially, (thanks for that), but now when Client connects it has 2 guns and host has no gun, on host screen it works as intendeed

Comment: Okay it almost works, now the player that joins later can't see the weapon of players already connected, that way host sees all weapons, player connected second sees only his, but when third player joins, he sees his weapon aswell.

Comment: Yeah you might need to implement a state updater. Like,  when player joins the game he requests other player's weapon and spawns it.

Comment: Also, you migth want to take a look at NetworkMessages: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetMessages.html
Theese are extreemely useful in some cases and give you a lot of control, since you can decide which client needs to receive a message(remember, RPC's are sent to all clients)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a duplicate of [Unity 5.1 Networking - Spawn an object as a child for the host and all clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359668/unity-5-1-networking-spawn-an-object-as-a-child-for-the-host-and-all-clients)

The idea discussed there is to synchronize network ID of the parent object, e.g. on the Server side while spawning:

```
var gun = Instantiate (...);
gun.parentNetId = this.netId;
NetworkServer.Spawn (gun);
```

And later on the clients:

```
// GunController.cs
[SyncVar]
public NetworkInstanceId parentNetId;

public override void OnStartClient()
{
    GameObject parentObject = ClientScene.FindLocalObject(parentNetId);
    transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);
}
```